# Reversing linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
node *rever(node *root)
{
node *prev = NULL;
node *xnew = NULL;

  while (root != NULL) {

  xnew = malloc(sizeof(root));
  xnew->value = root->value;
  xnew->next = prev;

  prev = xnew;
  root = root->next;
  }



  return xnew;
}
```

Hello I wrote this linked list reverse function. However it doesn't work(empty response): I suspect it's because of prev index getting overwritten. Could someone explain me whats going on? I know I could find working code on the internet but I wanna know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to know - use a debugger.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you create a new list which is reversed? You could just reverse the list in place and not create a new list which is reversed.

Comment: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."  The code is right (walk through orig list, and push copies of items onto a stack using newly allocated nodes. Just the malloc is wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

This looks close to correct.  One problem I see:  `sizeof(root)` is the same as `sizeof(node*)`.  That is, it's enough space for a pointer to a node.

You need enough space for an actual `node` struct.  So malloc `sizeof(*root)` bytes (or `sizeof(node)`, which is the same).

Answer (score 0):

```
    xnew = malloc(sizeof(root));
```

That should really be `sizeof(*root)` — you want a memory block the size of the structure pointed to, not the size of the pointer.  As a result, you're likely overwriting whatever happens to be sitting in memory just past the pointer-sized block you allocated, resulting in [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which could include anything from working as expected to [causing demons to fly out of your nose](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.std.c/ycpVKxTZkgw/S2hHdTbv4d8J).